# Read error while copying VOB files from DVD drive to hard disk

Tags: windows, dvd

I have old DVDs containing personal (family) recordings.

I want to copy the DVD files to PC, add menu and titles to these files using standard Video editor and share/stream video files.

The windows copy function or video programs hang after copying about 20% of files on DVD. Apparently, there are scratches on DVD that causes an error and the program keeps re-trying for a long time.

Are there any commands / Windows utilities / programs that will ignore errors and continue to copy/display as much as possible?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Although the content you're trying to get off the video, this is not really a video production question. You might be better off asking on Super User, you're more likely to get people with expertise on dealing with the problem there.

Comment: Have you tried using a conversion program like handbrake or MakeMKV this will read the disc and produce a format you can use in an NLE (to a degree of course)

Comment: Thanks, @stib. Should I delete the question from here?

Comment: See the methods at https://superuser.com/q/508679/114058

Comment: Thanks, @Gyan. The link provides good details and options to resolves the issue

Comment: cleaning the disks with some soft microfiber clothes may sometimes work. Try DVD decryptor but extract to a folder instead of extracting to iso (this is a feature in the software). This should get you as much files as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I could tell you in Linux (ddrescue), but for Windows, I'd start out looking at apps that get data from broken disk drives. Something that will skip over sectors it can't read.